# Fix a broken desktop GUI

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx

I've been running 12.04 on a NVidia GPU.  I attempted to install ATI's proprietary catalyst drivers and a second GPU.  Now the X-desktop will not start.

1. How do I refresh the borked desktop?
2. Can NVidia and ATI's HD series coexist?

"Will not start" may be a misnomer.  The background comes up but the (taskbar?) on the left doesn't come up and the icons on the desktop can't be clicked.  After a timeout I get a password request but then the desktop no longer shows.

I found a message from modem-manager trying to start saying it can't find /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket. That may or may not be helpful

lspci:

> 03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti] [10de:11c6] (rev a1)
>     Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device [3842:3650]
>     Kernel driver in use: nvidia
>     Kernel modules: nvidia_319_updates, nvidia_304, nvidia_304_updates, nouveau, ? nvidiafb
>
> 03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e0b] (rev a1)
>     Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device [3842:3650]
>
> 06:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] [1002:68f9]
>     Subsystem: Hightech Information System Ltd. Device [1787:2291]
>     Kernel modules: radeon
>   06:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300 Series] [1002:aa68]
>     Subsystem: Hightech Information System Ltd. Device [1787:aa68]
>     Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

Comment: We need the logs of the Xorg server and the drivers that you installed along with the specs (aka `lspci -nnk | grep -A5 VGA`) of the video cards. The xorg log you can find it at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16659635/Xorg.0.log

Comment: Can you edit your question, also do not use drop box since some users can't access dropbox.

Comment: Xorg.o.log is too big to insert into the question and the dropbox link is a public share. Why can't you read it?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the problem.

According to answer #1 at [Ubuntu 12.04 - default Radeon driver does not work at all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171933/ubuntu-12-04-default-radeon-driver-does-not-work-at-all) there were some missing drivers.

> To get hardware acceleration (tested on 12.04 Precise Pangolin), you
>   need to add four more packages:

```
sudo apt-get install xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
```

After installing them, the desktop successfully completed initialization on my nVidia display (which has been plugged in all along).  I suppose that was the "Magic" mentioned above.  Both devices show up in lspci but I have not yet tried out two monitors.  Moreover CTRL-ALT-F1 no longer opens a terminal so I can't say everything is perfect yet.

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106
[GeForce GTX 650 Ti] [10de:11c6] (rev a1)       Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp.
Device [3842:3650]      Kernel driver in use: nvidia    Kernel modules:
nvidia_319_updates, nvidia_304, nvidia_304_updates, nouveau, nvidiafb

03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio
Controller [10de:0e0b] (rev a1)         Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device
[3842:3650]

-- 06:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
[1002:68f9]     Subsystem: Hightech Information System Ltd. Device
[1787:2291]     Kernel driver in use: radeon    Kernel modules: fglrx,
radeon 06:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
[AMD/ATI] Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300 Series] [1002:aa68]
        Subsystem: Hightech Information System Ltd. Device [1787:aa68]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about coexisting without lots of magic, but to get the nVidia stuff going again, try:

Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get to a virtual terminal (I assume you just have a blinking cursor with a failed X), log in and then run:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

And that should get you going again.

Comment: Did you mean _install_? `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` does nothing useful (makes no changes).  X is only half-failed. (see edited question - above).

Comment: Yes, I missed that in my cut-n-paste editing. Changed to what I initally meant. Odd about the Ctrl-Alt-F1. How about Ctrl-Alt-F2? If you can get the virtual terminals to work you might try apt-get purge on all these packages (nvidia and the "magic" ones) and then install them again, perhaps in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

To reinstall a broken GUI-Desktop:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

References:

[Reinstall Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257470/reinstall-gnome)

[Ubuntu boots to black screen with cursor after upgrade (from 18.04 to 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279976/ubuntu-boots-to-black-screen-with-cursor-after-upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04/1279979#1279979)

[Ubuntu boots to a black screen with a blinking cursor after upgrading from 14.04 to 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770999/ubuntu-boots-to-a-black-screen-with-a-blinking-cursor-after-upgrading-from-14-04/1280004#1280004)

Press ALT + F3 or F4 or F5 to enter a Terminal.