# Startup script for turning/disable monitor off and on

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

So this is a problem for me since I have two monitors set up for my Ubuntu Desktop. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Ok, so first when I installed Ubuntu I had this problem with enabling the second monitor as at the same time not mirroring the two monitors. Ubuntu did not now how to set the required resolution. I searched for an answer and got one fixing my problem. I simply edited my xorg.conf file and added a virtual size for my desktop, now with the virtuyal resolution of 3840 1080. Log out and back in and it works and I can now use both of my monitors.

But, then after a few reboots, the secondary screen started to act weird. Like for example, when I drag a window over to that screen, the contours sticks and it looks really strange (a little like [this](http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/4554/22120951.jpg) if you know what I mean). So to get the secondary screen back to normal I have to go to the top right "start button" -> Displays... -> Select secondary monitor -> Turn it of -> Apply -> Keep Configuration -> Turn it on -> Apply -> Keep Configuration.

As you can imagine this is a little annoying and therefor it would be awsome if I could make a script that does this at every startup. A few commands for doing the same thing but in terminal would be all I need.

Hope you guys understand what I want to accomplish.

I have a Radeon HD7870 video card, so I use the drivers from ATI/AMD. I have catalyst center installed version 8.96.7-120312a-135598C-ATI. My primary screen, wich works super is connected through DP and my secondary screen through VGA. Both 1920x1080

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What drivers are you using?  This will impact the answer.

Comment: I have a Radeon HD7870 video card, so I use the drivers from ATI/AMD. I have catalyst center installed version 8.96.7-120312a-135598C-ATI. My primary screen, wich works super is connected through DP and my secondary screen through VGA. Both 1920x1080

Comment: Not in any way an answer but, I have found that the open radeon drivers plays much more nicely with my system (HD3870 hardware). The performance is good enough for me. YMMV.   http://askubuntu.com/questions/171902/why-isnt-ubuntu-using-the-open-source-amd-ati-drivers  might be useful for you.

Comment: So I should try to remove the proprietary driver and use the open source driver for radeon that is included with ubuntu?

Comment: That is my suggestion, yes.  In my scenario I have only seen improved behavior. In particular how the system(default tools) interacts with the driver.  I'm not going back to fglrx anytime soon. Keep in mind that my hardware is much older, so yours might not be as supported by the radeon driver.  I would still give it a try though.

Comment: I'm sorry but that didn't work at all. After removing ATIs driver, Ubuntu could not identify the monitors and presented the monitors a laptop screen. I would only like to know how I can disable my secondary monitor and then enable it again with commands. That way I can make it a startup script.

Comment: I'm really surprised that it failed monitor identification. I see that `amdcccle` http://dev.man-online.org/man1/amdcccle/ does not take any parameters so scripting will be tricky.  I'm afraid that's as helpful as I can be.

Comment: Hmm, okey, then I understand. Thankful for your help althought it didn't work out. I will probobly leave it as it is and then check if the radeon drivers work better after a half a year or so. Thanks man!